# for j in anagram(word[:i] + word[i+1:]): <- how it works?

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I built anagram generator. It works, but I don't know for loop for functions works at line 8, why does it works only in

```
for j in anagram(word[:i] + word[i+1:]):
```

why not

```
for j in anagram(word):
```

Also, I want to know what

```
for j in anagram(...)
```

means and doing...

what is `j` doing in this for loop?

this is my full code

```py
def anagram(word):
    n = len(word) 
    anagrams = []
    if n <= 1:
        return word
    else:
        for i in range(n):
            for j in anagram(word[:i] + word[i+1:]): 
                anagrams.append(word[i:i+1] + j) 
        return anagrams

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(anagram("abc"))
```

Comment: So, you built it without knowing how it works?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you can't write `for i in anagram(word)` is that it creates an infinite loop.

So for example if I write the recursive factorial function,

```
def fact(n): 
    if n <= 1: 
        return 1
    return n * fact(n - 1)
```

This works and is not a circular definition because I am giving the computer two separate equations to compute the factorial:

> *n*! = 1
>   *n*! = *n* (*n*-1)!

and I am telling it when to use each of these: the first one when *n* is 0 or 1, the second when *n* is larger than that. The key to its working is that eventually we stop using the second definition, and we instead use the first definition, which is called the “base case.” If I were to instead say another true definition like that *n*! = *n*! the computer would follow those instructions but we would never reduce down to the base case and so we would enter an infinite recursive loop. This loop would probably exhaust a resource called the “stack” rapidly, leading to errors about “excessive recursion” or too many “stack frames” or just “stack overflow” (for which this site is named!). And then if you gave it a mathematically invalid expression like *n*! = *n* *n*! it would infinitely loop and **also** it would be wrong even if it did not infinitely loop.

Factorials and anagrams are closely related, in fact we can say mathematically that

```
len(anagrams(f)) == fact(len(f))
```

so solving one means solving the other. In this case we are saying that the anagram of a `word` which is empty or of length 1 is just `[word]`, the list containing just that word. (Your algorithm messes this case up a little bit, so it's a bug.)

The anagram of any other word must have something to do with anagrams of words of length `len(word) - 1`. So what we do is we pull each character out of the word and put it at the front of the anagram. So `word[:i] + word[i+1:]` is the word except it is missing the letter at index *i*, and `word[i:i+1]` is the space between these -- in other words it is the letter at index *i*.

Answer (score 0):

**This is NOT an answer but a guide for you to understand the logic by yourself.**

Firstly you should understand one thing `anagram(word[:i] + word[i+1:])` is not same as `anagram(word)`

```
>>> a = 'abcd'
>>> a[:2] + a[(2+1):]
'abd'
```

You can clearly see the difference.

And for a clearer understanding I would recommend you to print the result of every word in the recursion. put a `print(word)` statement before the loop starts.